# In VB.NET how to talk to a byte-type named pipe server?

Tags: vb.net, message, named-pipes

I am writing a VB.net client to write to and read from a named pipe in byte transmission mode.
I learned from the MSDN article that CallNamedPipe() only works for message-type named pipes.

So do I have other choices, or do I have to change the pipe server code to message type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research, I now know that:

1. CallNamedPipe equals to CreateFile + TransactNamedPipe + CloseHandle. That's why it fails on byte type pipes.
2. In VB.net and VB, one can simply use CreateFile, WriteFile and ReadFile to talk to byte type named pipes.